# Youtube Search js function

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube

While i was searching at stackoverflow, i found the code below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#show").click(function () {
    getYoutube($("#Search").val());
});
```

});

```
function getYoutube(title) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + title + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.data.items) {
            $.each(response.data.items, function (i, data) {
                var video_id = data.id;
                var video_title = data.title;
                var video_viewCount = data.viewCount;
                $("#result").html(video_id);
            });
        } else {
            $("#result").html('false');
        }
    }
});
```

}

How can i edit the code to keep only the function?
I want to be able to use it like that : getYoutube(my_keywords);

Also, how can i save the function output to variable? something like :
var_name = getYoutube(my_keywords);
would be ok?

Thnx! ;)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use it as without `$(document).ready`. No, function does not return anything

To "return" value from Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(dataFromServer) {
        processServerOutput(dataFromServer);
    }
});

function processServerOutput(someString) {
    alert(someString);
}
```

Comment: okk and how can i edit the function to return a value? 
can you help me please? ;) :D

Comment: @Radwan `return variable`?

Comment: @Radwan but since it's Ajax, google for Ajax callback's, since returned value will be empty

Comment: so what can id do? gime some code i have been lost :/ :D

Comment: @Radwan edited answer, but there is lot of examples on internet!

Comment: yeah but i dont know ether js ether ajax so i cant understand them.. I know only python and php

Comment: can you edit the code i give and give me the code ready coz ether ur answer confuse me...